# pandas Numerical columns being treated as object and won't coerce

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, type-conversion, pandasql

I am having a hard time understanding what is going on with my sql to pandas data frame datatypes:

- User_ID is expected to be an 'object'.. which is fine.
- DATE is in the format of 201612, 201701, 201702, etc.  (year_number+month_number)
- INCOME is all numerical values such as 57.25, 50, 100.10, etc
- DEDUCTIONS is also numerical
- COUNT of  STORES would naturally be an integer...

I don't understand why my dataset is coming back with these count and sum fields as object as I cannot use operations such as   df.total_deductions.max().   I am failing to understand what could be causing this or how to fix it.

```
query = """ SELECT  
  date, 
   user_id,  
  sum(income) total_spend, 
 sum(deductions) total_deductions ,
  count(distinct stores) number_stores 
   FROM  db_table GROUP BY user_id """

df = pd.read_sql(query, jdbc_connection)

df.dtypes: 
date:  object 
user_id:  object 
total_spend:   float 
total_deductions:  object 
number_stores: object
```

I looked at the data.  I can't seem anything to indicate that would cause these counts or sums to be an object rather than a numeric value.
I tried using pd.to_numeric( each_of_my_columns,  error ='coerce') but this coerce options forces them to be "NaN".

Can someone hypothesize what could be going on here or how to solve this, since I assume I am doing something that should be obvious incorrectly?

Comment: i think it might be caused by the version of pandas can you try  df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) or df['each_column'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)?...not some object returned by sum might not be number at all...so converting column wise raise an error in version of pandas before 0.7.0 version

Comment: Show us a `df.head()`, would help to see what the actual data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be problem values have start or end whitespaces, which can be removed by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['number_stores']=pd.to_numeric(df['number_stores'].astype(str).str.strip(),error='coerce')
```

You can check it by convert to `list`:

```
print (df['number_stores'].tolist()[:20])
```

Comment: Got it, didn't understand why counts in sql was turning numerical values to objects but this fixed it..